# What capture filter can I use to capture only TCP and UDP traffic in tshark commandline interface?

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, wireshark, tshark

HTTP uses port 80. I found this on the internet and used **`-f "tcp port 80"`** as the capture filter for capturing only HTTP traffic:

```
tshark -i Ethernet -f "tcp port 80"
```

But since I am a newbie, searching for port used by TCP and that used by UDP has confused me, since they both appear to have so so many ports.

So what capture filter do I use to capture only TCP and UDP traffic.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To capture all tcp or udp traffic, you would use:

```
tshark -i Ethernet -f "tcp or udp"
```

Refer to the [pcap-filter man page](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html) for more information about capture filters.